# Hide desktop.ini file only, without hiding other "hidden files"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, windows-8.1, desktop.ini, thumbs.db

I want to hide `desktop.ini` files but preserve their functionality¹, keeping **all** other hidden files and protected system files visible on Windows 8 and above.

The reason: I like to see everything going on in my folders—*except* that annoying file sitting on Desktop, where only the things I created should be. A method for selectively hiding this and maybe other necessary but annoying files as `Thumbs.db` as well would be fantastic.

The obvious solution of disabling the setting for seeing hidden files *isn't an option* here.

1. I know of a method that works for older Windows which is simply toggling the "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)" folder option in Desktop folders only, keeping it off for the rest of the system. Unfortunately the folder settings became global on later versions, so that doesn't work.
2. The other solution I know is preventing the creation of the desktop.ini files altogether: http://jamesisin.com/a_high-tech_blech/index.php/2010/09/nevermore-be-bothered-by-desktop-ini/

   It's simple, but it kills future desktop customization. Once creating the key the changes you do to desktop won't stick.

I wonder if in all these years anyone came up with another solution where you can selectively hide—not delete—such files, retaining their functionality and without hiding everything else?

Thanks in advance!

¹By "functionality" I mean needing no user action to retain desktop customization changes, a fully automated way just like `desktop.ini` does. I.E.: Requiring the user to run a .bat or .reg file to undo/re-apply solution 2 at every desktop change isn't automated, so that's out.

Comment: Right click desktop.ini > Properties > Enable "Hidden"

Comment: The only thing that occurs to me is not to show hidden files and unhide everything except the ones you want to suppress. You may need a batch file for this, so that you can run it regularly to catch up with any new hidden files which may be created. What I do is to move the hidden files I'm not interested in over to an unused area on the right of the screen (after disabling auto-arrange, of course). I agree that it's annoying, but I have learnt to live with my work-round.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm afraid you didn't read the question at all.

Comment: @AFH That's a good idea, but more work than creating a batches to undo/redo the key change when changing the desktop, with the added downside than removing the hidden status will also remove any visual indication that those files are system files. Thanks for the idea though, that's good food for thought.

Comment: @Nihal Yes I did. You can hide/unhide individual files as needed if "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)" is off.

Comment: I always delete them.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I tested this on Win7... Right click desktop.ini > Properties > Enable "Hidden"... is already marked as Hidden, & greyed with no switch possible. Hide sys files off, of course, to see it in the first place.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's not greyed out for me (also on Windows 7).

Comment: @DavidPostill - I'd love to figure out what we have set differently, to give the two different results... but my Windows chops are not stellar [I'm better on Mac]

Comment: @Tetsujin I created desktopi.ini manually - maybe that's the difference?

Comment: Hmm.. just tested - It frees up the Hidden checkbox, but still only goes from 'opaque' to 'slightly transparent'

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok, it was a mistake of mine to not explicitly state that I not only don't hide system files but I show all hidden files. Because, you know, I _do_ like to see everything in my folders. Thus, your solution won't work.

Comment: what do you care about having the file? Just delete it. It has no function anyway for the desktop.

Comment: @Aganju If you think "Just delete it" is the solution, you've not been paying attention.

Comment: Created a suggestion on the Feedback Hub https://aka.ms/AA3quzy, similarly as when someone throw a cent into a fountain.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using a third party software, one working solution that I found is to use Wise Folder Hider (https://www.wisecleaner.com/wise-folder-hider-free.html).

This particular tool is (at least at the time of posting) free, and accomplishes hiding `desktop.ini` files without interfering with their functionality (so Desktop customization is retained).  I haven't noticed any negative side effects from using it.  It appears to work by registering a service.

Simply install and launch the tool and add the `desktop.ini` files (there were two on the Desktop in my case) by their full path to the list of hidden files.  That should do the job.

However, the drawback is that if you want to hide `desktop.ini` or `Thumbs.db` files from everywhere (not just the Desktop), this tool won't really do the job, since you have to hide files one by one.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem here is the Window's definitions of the word "hidden." Given the context of your question, I suspect the desktop.ini file is *still hidden* as far as Windows is concerned. "But I can see it." Yes... but the file is still **set** as hidden. What you have done is gone into the view settings for windows explorer and tell it to ignore whether or not the files that are still set hidden are shown regardless of their hidden state. This is represented by the "hidden" files being semi-transparent.

This is a global setting and can either be off globally or on globally. In fact, there are two of them, one that only applies to "system files" like the desktop.ini and thumbs.db files found scattered across your hard drive.And another which applies to all *other* hidden files. Which presents one option right there... stop showing all hidden system files and leave the non-system ones visible. It's what I do. After all, you aren't likely to mess with thumbs.db or desktop.ini manually anyway (and, in fact, shouldn't).

You could, I suppose, change every single other hidden system file on the computer's file system to no longer be hidden *except* the desktop.ini on your desktop and then change the global settings back hide. But that's a rather complicated way to hide a single file and next time you create a new folder and toss some pictures/music in it windows will make new desktop.ini and/or thumbs.db hidden files.

You could also hide all icons on the desktop (which would technically include the desktop.ini file) by right-clicking on a blank space on the desktop, going to view, and unchecking `Show Desktop Icons`. I've been doing this for a decade now and have yet to regret it. The Desktop has always been a dumping ground for every application's random trash and I can simply use the start menu/quick launch/pinned-to-task bar features of Windows instead.

Other than those, you will need some third party tool that either modifies the way the windows desktop works (dubious chances of finding such) or replaces/overlays the desktop with its own replacement (dubious chance of finding such and likely to create more problems than it solves).

Comment: Thanks for your input. To make it shorter let's agree we both know that hidden files retain the "hidden" attribute when visible, and that "hiding a file" refers to making the file invisible to the eye, not setting the attribute "hidden". As I mentioned in my question I want to see both system and common hidden files, so hiding one kind isn't an option. Also, removing the attribute would remove the visual cue, that's not a good idea. I won't hide my icons on desktop or stop using shortcuts there, that's a personal choice that doesn't apply to the issue at hand. (1/2)

Comment: There are third-party tools that supposedly can do this, but like you I'd like to avoid them. I've been thinking about trying to force Windows to place the `desktop.ini` files outside the screen (without disabling auto-align and such, of course). I'd have to write my own tool to do this, but lucking someone else already [researched](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639486/Save-and-restore-icon-positions-on-desktop) the subject. Unfortunately that wouldn't help with `Thumbs.db`, but I'll take what I can. (2/2)

Comment: Ah, apologies, for whatever reason I don't recall your question including anything that flagged you as knowledgeable... but it's clearly there now. I'll consider further and let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: "*It seems the problem here is the Window's definitions of the word "hidden.*" the problem is MS choice to give applications (and itself) the possibility to hide files in any folder, a dangerous nonsense, in order to use them to create local caches, faster than the registry, to store configuration data. It's part of the permanent MS attempts to push "news" and "live data" to the user for disguised advertising, along with all those [desktop gadgets which MS had to acknowledge they created vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490844/whats-the-gadget-vulnerability).

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite a while, yet Windows is still Windows with all its little papercuts and no native way to deal with them. In the meanwhile, I've used two solutions. Both require turning off the *Align icons to grid*, which doesn't make me very happy, but still...

The idea is to drag the files outside the screen boundaries and keep them there.

##### Method 1, DesktopOK

[DesktopOk](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopOK) is a small portable app that lets you save and restore the desktop layout. It's a very handy, but it's not automated.

To use it to hide the files you simply setup your desktop, drag the files away and save the layout, restoring it when the layout is changed for some reason, prompting desktop.ini to reappear.

##### Method 2, AHK script

Since I'm using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm) already for other tweaks this is my current solution. This one is automated, working at set intervals, and could be written to automatically move the files outside the screen every time the desktop layout changes, but I didn't feel it was so vital it warranted a hook only to watch for changes. I like it better because it's flexible, hunting down the desktop.ini files in particular and dragging them away without touching the other desktop items.

I've set the script that imports this snippet to load at startup, and besides running from time to time it can be called from the context menu, which more than good enough for me.

Here's the standalone version of the script. It was based on [this post](https:////www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/60982-deskicons-getset-desktop-icon-positions/?p=384341).

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent

; =========================================================================================
; Tray Menu
Menu, Tray, NoStandard
Menu, Tray, Tip, % "Desktop.ini hide"
Menu, Tray, Add, &Hide desktop.ini, TrayMenu
Menu, Tray, Add
Menu, Tray, Add, &Reload App, TrayMenu
Menu, Tray, Add
Menu, Tray, Add, E&xit, TrayMenu
Menu, Tray, Default, &Hide desktop.ini

hideDesktopIni()  ; Execute upon script load (startup)

; Run at intervals...
fn_hide := Func("hideDesktopIni").bind()
SetTimer, % fn_hide, % (0.5*60*60*1000)  ; Time in ms, eg run every half hour

return ; End of auto-execute
; =========================================================================================

hideDesktopIni(x=6000, y=20)  ; defaults...
{
    Critical
    static MEM_COMMIT := 0x1000, PAGE_READWRITE := 0x04, MEM_RELEASE := 0x8000
    static LVM_GETITEMPOSITION := 0x1010, LVM_SETITEMPOSITION := 0x100F, WM_SETREDRAW := 0x000B
    
    ControlGet, hwWindow, HWND,, SysListView321, ahk_class Progman
    if !hwWindow ; #D mode
        ControlGet, hwWindow, HWND,, SysListView321, A
    IfWinExist ahk_id %hwWindow% ; last-found window set
        WinGet, iProcessID, PID
    hProcess := DllCall("OpenProcess"   , "UInt",   0x438           ; PROCESS-OPERATION|READ|WRITE|QUERY_INFORMATION
                                        , "Int",    FALSE           ; inherit = false
                                        , "UInt",   iProcessID)
    if hwWindow and hProcess
    {   
        ControlGet, list, list, Col1
            VarSetCapacity(iCoord, 8)
            pItemCoord := DllCall("VirtualAllocEx", "UInt", hProcess, "UInt", 0, "UInt", 8, "UInt", MEM_COMMIT, "UInt", PAGE_READWRITE)
            Loop, Parse, list, `n
            {
                ; Retrieve list of desktop items
                SendMessage, %LVM_GETITEMPOSITION%, % A_Index-1, %pItemCoord%
                DllCall("ReadProcessMemory", "UInt", hProcess, "UInt", pItemCoord, "UInt", &iCoord, "UInt", 8, "UIntP", cbReadWritten)
                
                ; Check name and move if matches
                StringLower, deskIcon, A_LoopField
                if (deskIcon = "desktop.ini") {
                    coordinates := (x & 0xFFFF) | ((y & 0xFFFF) << 16)
                    SendMessage, %WM_SETREDRAW%, 0, 0
                    SendMessage, %LVM_SETITEMPOSITION%, % A_Index-1, %coordinates%
                    SendMessage, %WM_SETREDRAW%, 1, 0
                    ret := true
                }
            }
            DllCall("VirtualFreeEx", "UInt", hProcess, "UInt", pItemCoord, "UInt", 0, "UInt", MEM_RELEASE)
    }
    DllCall("CloseHandle", "UInt", hProcess)
    return ret
}


; Custom tray menu
TrayMenu:
    switch A_ThisMenuItem
    {
        case "&Hide desktop.ini":
            hideDesktopIni()
        return
        case "&Reload App":
            Reload
        return
        case "E&xit":
            ExitApp
        return
    }
return
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it, DELETE it and create a folder (or some other file) on the desktop witht he SAME NAME. Windows will not be able to create it again.

This question to me had NO IMPORTANCE until about 2 months ago when Explorer 1) started forcing my bottom row of icons up from the edge of the screen a whole icon's worth, RUINING my custom layout and 2) MOVED the desktop.ini file to the left edge of the screen where new files are created EVERY time the desktop was refreshed. Well, until then, for years, I had placed the desktop.ini file in the middle of a mess way out of the way and it STAYED there. Thanks, microsoft, for SCREWING WINDOWS UP AS ALWAYS -- god, can we say WINDOWS 8?

So anyhow, like i said, i didn't CARE about hiding desktop.ini until windows updated explorer and forced it to appear on the left edge all the damn time. The solution has been to create your own desktop.ini as a folder and move it to where I want so it can stay there, just like the file itself used to.

Comment: Sorry but the question also says to not affect the functionality given by the contents of the ini file. if you delete the file the file wont exist. hiding means just removing it from view without axing the file itself.